# how to store cursor object's data in an array

Tags: android, database, arrays, cursor

I want to ask about how to store data retrieved from a cursor object in an array. I am unable to do that and getting an null pointer exception because I am not able to initialize the size of the array? Where do I write that code and store all the data retrieved from cursor object in an array. Please I am unable to do that.

My code for retrieving the data from the cursor is below.

```
if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
            int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
            //results.add("Name: " + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried to improve the text of your question as it was hard to understand. Please don't use abbreviation and create simpler sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you have two values that you want to store. So a normal array will not solve the problem. You can use an ArrayList of a custom class. Or you use the Pair class.

Try this:

```
if (c != null ) {
    ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.put(new Pair<c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"), c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age")>));
            //firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
            //int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
            //results.add("Name: " + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Array. Use ArrayList or ArrayList> which are mutable. In the latter, init the arraylist then the HashMap and populate it with the put(key, value) method and finally add the HashMap to the ArrayList

Comment: is not any other way for achiving this..can i not store the valus in array??

Comment: ArrayList is mutable, array is not. Also, you want to store multiple values per index, and therefore I would suggest ArrayList containing HashMap or Pair model.

Comment: I use SimpleAdapter or a self-made ArrayAdapter which inherits from BaseAdapter. If you use an ArrayAdapter, you could make a Person model, ArrayAdapter<Person> and then the Adapter is ArrayAdapter<Person>

Answer (score 0):

and again ...

i'm assuming that you need this array for ArrayAdapter

for Cursor use ([Simple](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html))[CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)